# Regular Expression in Html Dom Parser/PHP

Tags: php, regex

source code:

```
<div id="point">9</div>
<div id="point">REAL POINT: 9</div>
```

and parser code:

```
$point = $html->find('div[id=point]');
```

so, when you write `$point[0]` it will be first, and the other will be second.

But sometimes i need to make an algorithm like this: "find the divs with id point and must **begin** with REAL POINT: "

We can find

```
$point = $html->find('div[id=point]')->innertext=' REAL POINT:';
```

But that finds only divs include ' REAL POINT:'

But i have to find divs innertext **begin** 'REAL POINT:'

How can i find?

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id, they are supposed to be unique.  I suggest you use `<div class="point">` instead.  Even better `<div class="point">` and `<div class="realpoint">` .

Comment: I don't already. Target source does it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use stripos for case sensitive.

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=point]') as $element) {
    if ( strpos($element->innertext, 'REAL POINT:') !== FALSE ) {
        // something here
    }
}
```

You could also do a search for the string exactly at the start:

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=point]') as $element) {
    if ( strpos($element->innertext, 'REAL POINT:') === 0 ) {
        // something here
    }
}
```

But if you want to remove whitespace before the first character in a div:

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=point]') as $element) {
    if ( strpos(trim($element->innertext), 'REAL POINT:') === 0 ) {
        // something here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is semi answer Aram.
I wish there was ->innertext^='REAL POINT'; But it doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ and the examples that come with the download. They seem to foreach loops a fair bit, but yeah, they should have provided something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath:

```
//div[@id='point' and starts-with(., 'REAL POINT:')]
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The `starts-with` function requires at least 2 arguments. Source: [http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-starts-with](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-starts-with).

Comment: Yes and it is not simple html dom parser's element.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMDocument](http://ca.php.net/DOMDocument) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/DOMXPath):

**Example** (http://codepad.org/pkdd3Suz):

```
<?php

$html = <<<END
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="point">9</div>
        <div id="point">REAL POINT: 9</div>
    </body>
</html>
END;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="point" and starts-with(., "REAL POINT:")]');

if ( $nodes )
    foreach ( $nodes as $node )
        echo $node->textContent . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: This code works fine but not with this HTML sample, which is invalid and triggers a warning: *ID point already defined*

Comment: probably a better class than simple html dom parser